# Wordpress mail return false

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I am using wordpress mail and it returning me false.
pleas help me to checkout what's wrong in code.

```
$headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1' . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= 'From: abc@gmail.com';
$to ='user@gmail.com';
$mail_resp = wp_mail( $to , 'The subject', 'The message',$headers );
    if($mail_resp){
echo "Mail send Sucessfully";
}
 else{
    echo "Mail Not send";
 }
```

i am getting response mail not send Please help me to out of this what's wrong in this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could be your headers. "For the string version, **each** header line (beginning with From:, Cc:, etc.) is delimited with a newline ("\r\n") (advanced)". Which seems to indicate to me that you need to put a `\r\n` at the end of the From: header, too. (Or use the array version of the syntax.) Also, "For this function to work, the settings SMTP and smtp_port (default: 25) need to be set in your php.ini file."—does WordPress successfully send you mail in other circumstances? e.g. if you register as a new user, etc.?

Comment: hello matt, i try as you told me at the end of line i put \r\n at the end of the header.  also use array version but with no luck

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: abc@gmail.com' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: i check error in my error log.

error is :
 PHP Warning:  mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at &quot;localhost&quot; port 25, verify your &quot;SMTP&quot; and &quot;smtp_port&quot; setting in php.ini or use ini_set() .

My site is hosted on Godaddy.

Comment: Well, if godaddy don't provide an SMTP server on port 25, that would explain it...

Comment: Check this link and implemement the add_filter functionality to change your email address and try it http://www.butlerblog.com/2011/07/08/changing-the-wp_mail-from-address-in-wordpress-without-a-plugin/

Comment: Thank So much guys for helping me.

problem solve.

Thank You So Much

Comment: Add the solution to your question so helpful for other users having same problem